# disable wrong typescript error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, interact.js

I have installed 'interact.js' with jspm (and npm for typescript to be happy). The app runs fine but my code shows errors:

```
import { interact } from 'interact.js/interact'
// ==> typescript error: TS2307: Cannot find module 'interact.js/interact'
```

I suppose the problem has something to do with the npm module containing '.js' but I am not sure. Anyway, is there a way to fix this either by

A. Help Typescript find the module
B. Disable this specific error (since it works fine)

PS: here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{ "exclude":
  [ "node_modules"
  , "jspm_packages"
  , ".git"
  , "typings/browser"
  , "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
, "compilerOptions":
  { "outDir": "dist"
  , "target": "es5"
  , "sourceMap": true
  , "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
, "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Do you have the definition (.d.ts) file installed? (And no, I don't think there is a way to disable specific errors in TypeScript - irritating, as there's a bug in the compiler making 3 show up in my project at the minute... Hopefully they add that soon)

Comment: There is no interact.js definition file but this would not solve the module path resolution error...

Comment: If I delete one of the definitions for a library in my project, I get the same error - the TypeScript compiler will not recognize that a module exists without a .d.ts file, unless there's one built in to the NPM package. See this issue on the Typescript repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3019. There should be a solution to this in TypeScript 2.0 when it comes out, apparently: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615.

Comment: I forked the project, added a d.ts file with some interface definitions and it seems to fix (and type check my code correctly). I will propose a pull request to interact.js author with my types... :-) thansk !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! I think this trips most TypeScript developers up first time around, it's pretty unintuitive. Mind if I write this up as an answer, in case other people stumble across this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler/language service doesn't actually resolve module names through the filesystem or your `package.json` like you might expect - [it instead uses the definition (`.d.ts`) files that define the type information](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3019#issuecomment-98821868).

While it's not the most intuitive thing in the world, their reasoning for it wasn't entirely unreasonable - without a definition file, it's impossible to know what type the thing being imported is, and they were somewhat cagey about making the compiler default to just setting imports to the `any` type.

So in short, the solution to this problem is simply to install the definition files if available, or write/stub out your own if not. [They'll be making this easier in TypeScript 2.0 by the sounds of it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615), but even as it stands, it takes very code to create a dummy definition:

```
declare module "interact.js/interact" {
    export var interact: any;
}
```

Comment: I created a complete types definition file: https://github.com/lucidogen/interact.js and asked author if he/she wants to pull the changes in the library. Thanks :-) !

Comment: @gaspard: Good on you for going to the effort of making a full definition!